# large gap between tasks in same job/stage in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a job that should take less than 1 sec.
In this case it takes around 10-12 sec. drilling down into one stage, shows that the tasks are running fine, you can see that the maximal, long running task, took 0.4 sec:
[image: Summary metric]

however, when looking at the timeline, you can see that there is a large gap (~10 sec.) between some tasks under the same stage:
[image: tasks timeline]

is there anything I'm missing?
what should I configure in order to avoid that long-time gap?

**Edit:**

Here is the entire list of tasks in the timeline, it seems pretty balanced
[image: entire tasks timeline]

Answer (score 0):

Try to repartition your RDDs in order that each partition contains the same volume of data. This kind of problems often happens when partitions contain largely imbalanced data volume. Check this article, it may help understand the partitioning aspect and its effects on performance :
https://dzone.com/articles/apache-spark-performance-tuning-degree-of-parallel

Comment: It doesn't look like skew is an issue from the UI.

Comment: I've edited the original post (as I can't add images in comments), you can see that the partitions are pretty balanced

Comment: which Spark version are you using? I had the same problem with Spark 2.3.2 and it disappeared after I switched to 2.4.4

Comment: 2.4.0, but I'll look at the documentation till 2.4.4 to see any change in this area. Thanks